# Residual window shadows in Windows 10 (minor annoyance)

Tags: windows-10, display-settings

Running into a weird problem that's almost impossible to JFGI because I don't know the proper terms for the process.

I have a Windows placeholder shadow, like you get in preview mode that isn't going away. This is hard to duplicate and occurs randomly. All of the currently open programs were systematically closed and it remains.

[image: **<code>screenshot</code>**]

It has a focus ID, since opening a new program will place it above the shadow. Changing resolution does not make it go away, nor does LOff/LOn.

This is a relatively new work laptop, so the hardware and drivers should be fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do the dimensions of the container remind you of any applications? Does the problem occur in safe mode? I wonder if AutoHotKey's "Active Window Spy" can ID the container.

Comment: Graphical glitches like this typically are solved by restarting File Explorer.  As for finding the cause, unless you can reproduce the problem, there really isn't enough information to submit an answer.

Comment: It's possible that it's part of a popup, as I usually have quite a bit of apps open, but I can't remember anything at that size/position

Comment: I restarted Explorer and it didn't resolve the issue. This makes me think either: Windows 10 added a sub process for desktop graphics, or there's a process wrapper on an app that's emulating the drop shadow. I've also restarted Java and a few other processes but it's still there.

Again, doing a restart always fixes it, so it's likely a specific set of steps that causes it. Will keep looking for replication

Comment: Could be a video driver issue, if you restart the video driver does it disappear?  You can use: Win+Ctrl+Shift+B to manually restart it.

Comment: Negative on the video driver, but thanks for the hotkey. Didn't know such a thing existed